# Does there exist a field $K$ and $x \in K$ with $K(x^{1/4})=K(x^{1/2}) \neq K$

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

I want to know if there exists a field $K$ and $x \in K$ with $K(x^{1/4})=K(x^{1/2}) \neq K$.

My attempt thus far: if $K(x^{1/2}) \neq K$ then $x^{1/2} \notin K$ so the minimal polynomial of $x^{1/2}$ over $K$ has degree $>1$ and is therefore $X^2-x$. Then $[K(x^{1/2}):K] = 2$ and $\{1, x^{1/2}\}$ is a $K$-basis for $K(x^{1/2})$. Since $K(x^{1/4})=K(x^{1/2})$ we have $x^{1/4} \in K(x^{1/2})$ so there exist $a, b \in K$ such that $x^{1/4} = a + bx^{1/2}$.

Then I tried rearranging and squaring both sides etc to see if I could find something useful but I didn't get anywhere... Any tips? I don't even know whether such a $K$ exists at all!

Comment: There is also $\Bbb{F}_{7^2}=\Bbb{F}_7((-1)^{1/2})=\Bbb{F}_7((-1)^{1/4})$ because $4 \nmid 7-1, 8 | 7^2-1$

Answer (score 3):

Yes. $K= \mathbb R$, $x=-1$.

*Added*: Generalising comments by k.stm and Jyrki Lahtonen, as well as reuns under the OP, I claim that assuming $char(K) \neq 2$, such an $x \in K$ exists if and only if $-1$ is **not** a square in $K$. The proof, as well as the case $char(K)=2$, are left as exercise.

Comment: And more generally, whenever we have $\sqrt 2 ∈ K$, a primitive $8$-th root of unity can be written as $ζ_8 = \frac {1+\mathrm i} {\sqrt 2} ∈ K(\mathrm i)$ for some primitive $4$-th root of unity $\mathrm i$, as then $ζ_8^2 = \mathrm i$ … So $K(ζ_8) = K(\mathrm i)$ with $ζ_8$ and $\mathrm i$ being a quartic and square root of $-1$ respectively.

Comment: Also works over $\Bbb{Q}$ with $x=-4=(2i)^2=(1+i)^4$ :-)

Answer (score -2):

$s=x^{1/4}$ , $d= x^{1/2}$

s£ k(d)==> s=a+bd ===> s^2 =a^2 +b^2d^2 +2abd ==> d=a^2+b^2x+2adb 
===> d( 1-2a) = a^2 +x 
d= ( 1-2ab)^(-)  ( a^2+xb^2)  , if 1-2ab#0 ==> d£K but this absurde since  k( d) #k  sorry i have note Latex for better redaction

Comment: put dollar signs before and after your maths in order to render MathJax. I've edited to do some for you, to see.  For ==> you want \implies inside a pair of dollar signs.

Comment: I'm trying to show whether or not such a field exists, rather than assume $K(d) \neq K$ and then reach a contradiction.